# Display more items when more link selected using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display list of items, when I click more link it should display 10 more items in the list.
Here is my current code:

```
<div ng-repeat="items in itemList()">
{{items.name}}
</div>
```

and my controller is:

```
$scope.itemsList = function(){
return service.getItemList();
}
```

How do I add more link under the items, display 10 more items when I click 'more'

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the limitTo filter and use a button with ngModel to change the value that is limited. Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

```
<div ng-repeat="items in itemList() | limitTo: displayNum">
  {{items.name}}
</div>
<button ng-click="increaseBy(10)">Show More</button>
```

Controller Function:

```
$scope.displayNum = 10;
$scope.increaseBy = function(num) {
  $scope.displayNum +=num;
}
```

Comment: He'll also have to modify the getItemList() method and the resource endpoint to support pagination. As it is now, the request appears to get everything at once.

Comment: The asker was not clear about that but yes, if the asker also wants the button click to make a get request and update the data then that would be necessary. It would also be a good idea to not call itemList() inside of ng-repeat.